# how to click on an element which comes under a toaster message

Tags: selenium, exception

hi im into selenium automation course and as part of our project im automationg a web application. when i add users toaster message appears as User added succesfully. after this step i have to signout, but the signout element gets overllaped by the toaster. and error Element not clickable exception comes. i tried to give explicit wait, javascriptexecutor click. but its not working.

attaching my code:

```
public static void waitForElementToBeClickable(WebDriver driver, WebElement target) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(EXPLICIT_WAIT));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable ((target)));

}

public void isUserMenuLoaded() {
        
    WaitUtility.waitForElementToBeClickable(driver, userMenu);          
        
}
    
public SignOutPage clickOnUserMenu() {      
        
    PageUtility.clickOnElement(userMenu);
    return new SignOutPage(driver);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the toast has close button you can wait for the toast appearance, then click the close button and wait until toast is disappeared.
Otherwise you should wait until toast disappeared and only after that you will be able to click the logout button.
You can enforce the process by clicking the logout button with JavaScript click but this is not recommended since this is not the way real user can do via the site UI.